# Responsive Design - Hidden accordion tab widths

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

http://dev.goforadventure.com/?post_type=trips&p=108

Hello,

Please squeeze the browser closer together until you see the accordion form with the little arrows to the right.

There is a div with a featured background image above the set of tabs (this is Wordpress)

When the tabs are closed, the width of that image div depends on how much space the post title/h1 above it is taking - if I make that font size larger, the picture will stretch larger with it.

If you open the first or last tabs, they have a large amount of text in it - this also causes more of the photo to show.

I am assuming because the div has width:auto applied to it, it isn't showing that much background because the content in the accordions are hidden by default.

Any idea to trick the image div into thinking theres more space there so the image and accordion tabs will stretch across the entire browser while theyre closed?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `width:auto` on the div that has the image and set it to 100%, you will notice nothing happens. Then we look at the container element of that div, the one that has `id="content"` and `role="main"`  That div has `float:left`. Remove the float in your media queries, and it will show as you want.